# How to create trasparent activity when i click Floating action button

Tags: android

First sorry for my bad English ,I am creating activity within that activity , i create floating action button ,when i click Floating Action Button on click action i show one activity it working fine but how to change my activity to transparent activity with no action bar
i change manifest file but getting some errors
mainifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.aa.bunny.aabunny.Main2Activity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main22Activity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
<style name="Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Comment: What errors  you are getting?

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aa.bunny.aabunny/com.aa.bunny.aabunny.Main2Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.@JIGAR

Comment: application theme in try  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: Min sdk 11 set and try

Comment: yes it getting but but not come with background color like above image@RaviVGHL

Answer (score 1):

Change activity theme to achieve transparency.
create a style like this

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

and use this in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".TransparentActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
```

Happy coding...

Comment: Error:(35, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.Transparent').@sreejin

Comment: create theme with name="Theme.Transparent" on the style.xml with above mentioned specifications and add that theme to manifest.

Comment: can u change the parent="android:AppTheme".

Comment: after changing  my parent getting this error cant resolve symbol "android:AppTheme", i post my entire style.xml code in above have please theme where i did wrong @sreejin

Comment: i need to create any new style.xml @sreejin

Comment: no need to create new style.xml update the existing file.

Comment: What the exact errors you are getting?? Is app crashes??

Comment: when i click floating action b utton i gt this error unfortunatly app stoped@sreejin

Answer (score 0):

You can apply theme like..

```html
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Or else you can also create your own theme in style..

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

You can also Set background of the activity as a transparent png image or a transparent color code